# Active Directory ADUser whenCreated Property

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've created (Server 2019) an ADUser: TestUser100.

```
New-ADUser -name TestUser100
```

This user has a property: whenCreated ("11.05.2021 15:00:00"), when I try to find the user:

```
Get-ADUser -filter{whenCreated -eq "11.05.2021 15:00:00"} -properties whenCreated
```

I've got nothing, when I search after: Created it works,  why?

```
Get-ADUser -filter{Created -eq "11.05.2021 15:00:00"} -properties Created
```

Comment: I haven't had time to research this fully, but my guess is that `Created` is a calculated property that's a copy of the `whenCreated` property from AD converted to local time as a `DateTime`, whereas `whenCreated` is an AD generalized string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `whenCreated` attribute is stored as string in AD with this format `20111101000413.0Z`. (*zulu format*)

When you compare that to another string `11.05.2021 15:00:00`, the result will be $false.

PowerShell conveniently maps that attribute to property `Created`, which is the whenCreated string converted to a Datetime object.
Because in your filter `Created` is on the left side of the equation, the string you give it is converted by PowerShell to a Datetime object and all compares as you expect.

BTW `-Filter` is a **string**, not a scriptblock, so should be

```
"Created -eq '11.05.2021 15:00:00'"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ADUser` is expecting a `DateTime` object when you filter by `whenCreated` or `whenChanged`.

This should work:

```
$date = '11.05.2021 15:00:00' -as [datetime]

Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -eq $date}
```